# Two almost exact lists: If the column at the right have a specific value, then copy it at the left (excel)

Tags: excel

I am working with excel.

I have almost two identical columns and I need some of the different results of the column at the right to be at the column at the left.

They look like this....

```
A      B
Yes    Yes
No     No
No     Maybe
Yes    Yes
Yes    Maybe
No     NA
Yes    Yes
No     Maybe
Yes    NA
No     No
```

I need new column A that contains the "Maybe" and maintain the values of the A when is NA in the B column... So it should look like this....

```
A      B        C
Yes    Yes      Yes
No     No       No
No     Maybe    Maybe
Yes    Yes      Yes
Yes    Maybe    Maybe
No     NA       No
Yes    Yes      Yes
No     Maybe    Maybe
Yes    NA       Yes
No     No       No
```

I have tried different things with IF formula, Match formula and Vlookup formula, but I have not reach a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sample data covers all possible combinations of `Yes, No, NA, & Maybe` then you can recreate your output column using the below formula and filling down as necessary

```
=IF(B2="NA",A2,IF(B2="Maybe",B2,B2))
```

which can be simplified to

```
=IF(B1="NA",A1,B1)
```

[image]

---

*If you have not provided all combinations of values then this likely will not work and you will need to update your sample data. This solution assumes:*

1. `Column A` can only contain `Yes & No`
2. `Column B` can only contain `Yes & No & NA & Maybe`
3. There is no instance where one column is `Yes` and the other is `No`